# w command in Vim doesn't work properly with Python

Tags: python, vim, command

I get this weird problem when working in Python in my vim, when I hit w to move or delete for instance it won't move to the proper position. For instance, let's say I have the following:

```
email_message.walk()
```

If my caret is at the beginning and I hit w it would be expected that it moved to the W of walk, instead it moves to the closing parenthesis.

Comment: `w` moves to a word boundary.  That's usually a space/new-line/tab/end-of-text/start-of-text.

Comment: Actually, I'd expect it to move to `.` It seems that you are getting `+w` behaviour (shift+w) instead of just `w`. Make sure you don't have Caps on and have no mappings specific to the python filetype that might cause this. You could just try `:noremap w w` to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: might be a plugin thing, do you get the same error in other file-types? 
`W` (capital) should move to the closing parens, `w` should move to the `.` before walk.

Comment: If you start at the beginning of the line, 'w' command should move to the '.', next w should go to 'w' of 'walk', next to open paren '('. Are you being confused by the highlighting of the parens when your position is on the open paren(?)

Comment: I just tried it myself.  Before `dw`: `email_message.walk()`.  After `dw`: `.walk()`.  `DW` deletes all of `email_message.walk()`.  Are you sure you're not hitting `W` rather than `w`?

Comment: I'm certain I'm not hitting W, it works fine with other languages, it's just Python that's the issue, and yes sorry I did mean it should move to . not the w. Seems to only happen with the .

Comment: What is the output of `set iskeyword?` in a python file and in another file with a differnet filetype?

Comment: @romainl my apologies, I posted my answer and didn't see your comment (I was on my phone).  If you want to post an answer about 'isk' I'll remove mine.

Comment: What about me upvoting yours, instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm almost positive the the problem here lies in the 'iskeyword' option.  Motions like `w` and `b` move to a word boundary as defined by this option.  I'm betting you have a plugin installed that is setting adding '.' and changing this behavior.

See `:help 'iskeyword'` for more info about this option and `:verbose set iskeyword?` to see what last set this option.

Comment: This is what I got form the verbose set iskeyword:

iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,.,(
        Last set from ~/.vimrc